# Table spread remaining space

Tags: html, deployment, html-table, max, space

How do you spread the remaining space of the table's cols? Like I want to have a table which has the following columns:

- id: should be as small (width) as possible, as I dont want a lot of whitespaces
- title: should take as much space as possible
- content: should take as much space as possible
- actions: (edit delete) should be as small as possible

Here is a scaffold of what I want to do:

```
| <--------------------------------- MAX WIDTH ---------------------------------> |

| id |            title            |            content            |    action    | < this is what i want
+----+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+--------------+
| 23 | test1                       | 123080asdu0a                  | edit  delete |
| 32 | test2                       | 123080asdu0a                  | edit  delete |
...
```

How do you deploy the remaining space (100% - id's width - action's width divided by 2) to both the title's and content'S col?

Answer (score 1):

Set the small columns' `width` to `1px` (`0` doesn't work). The content will stretch this, but will be as small as possible.

Set the large columns' `width` to `50%`. This will make them the same width (unless one has a lot more text than the other and requires more space).

To keep "edit" and "delete" on the same line, use a container `div` or `span` and set `white-space: nowrap` which would prevent word wrapping.

I've made a Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/RSsNS/

**HTML**:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="small">ID</td>
        <td class="big">Title</td>
        <td class="big">Content</td>
        <td class="small">Action</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="small">23</td>
        <td class="big">Test 1</td>
        <td class="big">123080asdu0a</td>
        <td class="small">
            <div>
                edit delete
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="small">32</td>
        <td class="big">Test 2</td>
        <td class="big">123080asdu0a</td>
        <td class="small">
            <div>
                edit delete
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**:

```
table {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px dashed #AAA;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.small {
    width: 1px;
}
.big {
    width: 50%;
}
td > div {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Can I handle it dynamically using any other value for big's width?

Comment: Not in CSS. Perhaps you can make something in JS to do that.

Comment: Just a guess: maybe with CSS3's new pseudo classes? Like nth-child or so?

Comment: The thing is, CSS doesn't have operators and variables like `=`, so you can't force the two cells to be the same width.